# Beta: public or private?

Tags: discussion, beta

I thought we were in private beta. Today, I received an email saying

> Please share a link to the site with anyone you think might be interested in our community:
>
> http://cooking.stackexchange.com

This seems to imply that it's public so I sent the link out. However, when they log in, they're told that it's a private beta.

If it's still supposed to be private: so be it, but why send out this email encouraging us to invite people?

Comment: Unrelated: it's interesting that 50 min.s after posting this question, there are 0 views but 1 up-vote

Comment: Probably a boilerplate message that they didn't bother to change for the private beta.  But in any case, I believe that the private beta is only 7 days, which means that those people will be able to register in just 2 more days.

Comment: Indeed, the number of views has seemed odd to me for many of these.

Comment: According to Area51 it should go public around noon PST today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't quite sure what to make of the email either. According to area 51, there are still two more days of private beta.

In the same batch of emails, I also received one for gaming.stackexchange.com, which was very similar but that site has just gone into public beta.